# How come Google Sign-In doesn't require the server to send the client_secret?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin

In Oauth2.0, the client must send the client secret via a "back channel" to the authorization server to make sure the authorization (code) grant is correct and get it exchanged with an access token. However, with Google Sign-In, the backend server code (in python) to verify the "authorization grant" doesn't seem to need to send the client secret:

```
    # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
```

how come this is?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you make this call authorization code grant flow has completed. The client had already exchanged the code for the access token while authenticating with client id and secret.

This call is to simply verify token signature.

See https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html